# Unable to import tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am getting the following error when trying to import tensorflow

> (tflow)sameer@sameer-Inspiron-1545 ~ $  python Python 2.7.5+ (default,
>   Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08)  [GCC 4.8.1] on linux2 Type "help",
>   "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> > > > import tensorflow as tf Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File
> > > >         "/home/sameer/tflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py",
> > > >         line 24, in 
> > > >             from tensorflow.python import *   File "/home/sameer/tflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py",
> > > >         line 49, in 
> > > >             from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "/home/sameer/tflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> > > >         line 52, in 
> > > >             raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> > > >         "/home/sameer/tflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> > > >         line 41, in 
> > > >             from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/home/sameer/tflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> > > >         line 28, in 
> > > >             _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/home/sameer/tflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
> > > >         line 24, in swig_import_helper
> > > >             _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description) ImportError:
> > > >         /home/sameer/tflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so:
> > > >         undefined symbol: PyBytes_AsStringAndSize
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: Must be the issue with tensorflow dependencies

Comment: Are you able to provide more environment info e.g. OS version, tensorflow version, with GPU etc?

Comment: ubuntu ,tenserflow 1.2.1